# JavaFX Disable a node, but turnoff disabled psuedoclass

Tags: javafx-8

I have a styling question.

I have a stage with two separate panes. When the user is on pane 1 they should be able to tab between all the input fields in pane 1 and the toolbar for the stage but tab shouldn't take then into pane 2. Same when pane 2 is active cycle the controls on pane 2 then toolbar but not pane 1.

To accomplish this I disable pane 2 when pane 1 becomes active and vice versa.

The users are complaining that non active pane looks washed out. I'm wondering if there is a way to disable the pane but not have it change the current shading?

Basically I would like to set the pane disabled but not the pseudo class to disabled on anything under it.

Basically I have a method which does this:

```
setContentNodeDisabled(Boolean value) {
    contentNode.setDisabled(value);
    //I tried this -- But this didn't work
    contentNode. pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("disabled"), false);
}
```

I need to keep the disabled styling the same for normal things, but in this case we are using each pane to create an MDI type experience, so only one can be active, so ideally the node would look active, even though it was disabled - preventing keyboard navigation to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do the following:

```
setContentNodeDisabled(Boolean value) {
    contentNode.setDisabled(value);
    if(value && !contentNode.getStyleClass().contains("myDisabledPane")){
        contentNode.getStyleClass().add("myDisabledPane");
    } else if(!value && contentNode.getStyleClass().contains("myDisabledPane")){
        contentNode.getStyleClass().remove("myDisabledPane");
    }

}
```

Added the following CSS:

```
.myDisabledPane .label:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .button:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .toggle-button:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .radio-button:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .check-box:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .hyperlink:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .menu-button:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .split-menu-button:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .slider:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .scroll-bar:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .scroll-pane:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .progress-bar:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .progress-indicator:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .text-input:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .choice-box:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .combo-box-base:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .date-cell:disabled > *, /* This is set on children so border is not affected. */
.myDisabledPane .list-view:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .tree-view:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .table-view:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .tree-table-view:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .tab-pane:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .titled-pane:disabled > .title,
.myDisabledPane .accordion:disabled > .titled-pane > .title,
.myDisabledPane .tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .menu:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .menu-item:disabled > .label,
.myDisabledPane .menu-item:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .list-cell:filled:selected:focused:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .list-cell:filled:selected:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .tree-cell:filled:selected:focused:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .tree-cell:filled:selected:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .tree-cell > .tree-disclosure-node:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .tree-table-row-cell > .tree-disclosure-node:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .table-row-cell:selected:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .tree-table-row-cell:selected:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .table-cell:selected:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .tree-table-cell:selected:disabled,
.myDisabledPane .spinner:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 1.0;
}
```

This seems to work except is is a broad stroke and real disabled fields while still disabled look enabled.